# How to remove specific array elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

> var array = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2', '12-0', '575-12', '279-12', '280-12', '412-12', '423-12', '424-12', '425-12', '291-12', '0-12', '449-12']

and I would like to remove elements that contain "-12" and "-0"

Expected Result = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2']

How can I achieve this expected result in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `.filter`.

Example:

```js
var array = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2', '12-0', '575-12', '279-12', '280-12', '412-12', '423-12', '424-12', '425-12', '291-12', '0-12', '449-12'];

var filtered = array.filter(item => !item.includes('-12') && !item.includes('-0'));
```

After executing this code, `filtered` becomes `['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2']`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=de) method in combination with [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes?retiredLocale=de) method.

Here is an example:

```js
let array = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2', '12-0', '575-12', '279-12', '280-12', '412-12', '423-12', '424-12', '425-12', '291-12', '0-12', '449-12']


let newArray = array.filter((element) =>
        !element.includes('-12') && !element.includes('-0')
)

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the Array.filter combined with String.includes methods. The Array.filter method creates a new Array with each item that results in a positive condition.

```js
let array = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2', '12-0', '575-12', '279-12', '280-12', '412-12', '423-12', '424-12', '425-12', '291-12', '0-12', '449-12']

let filteredArray = array.filter(item => (!item.includes("-12")) && !item.includes("-0"))

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Reference:

- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=de)
- [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes?retiredLocale=de)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find "12" and "0" *at any position* in the string (being the first *or* the second number) you can use a regular expression with `\b` symbolising a word boundary:

```js
var array = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2', '12-0', '575-12', '279-12', '280-12', '412-12', '423-12', '424-12', '425-12', '291-12', '0-12', '449-12','3-120','112-14','12-7'];

const res = array.filter(el=>![/\b0\b/,/\b12\b/].some(rx=>rx.test(el)));

console.log(res)
```

The word boundaries in the `rx` ensure that elements like `'3-120','112-14'` will *not* be removed from the result set.

Instead of using two regular expressions you can - for the given problem - combine the search requirements into one:

```js
var array = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2', '12-0', '575-12', '279-12', '280-12', '412-12', '423-12', '424-12', '425-12', '291-12', '0-12', '449-12','3-120','112-14','12-7'];

const res = array.filter(el=>!/\b(?:0|12)\b/.test(el));

console.log(res)
```

And, of course, if you only want to remove the elements when the numbers `0` and `12` appear after the (last) "-", you can do the following:

```js
var array = ['20-2', '319-2', '161-2', '320-2', '12-0', '575-12', '279-12', '280-12', '412-12', '423-12', '424-12', '425-12', '291-12', '0-12', '449-12','3-120','112-14','12-7'];

const res = array.filter(el=>!/-(?:0|12)$/.test(el));

console.log(res)
```